# How to create numbered variables used SAS array

Tags: sas

I have a large dateset where I need to dynamically create over 10 columns, however the amount of data makes for unnecessary long code blocks. Is is possible to simplify the code below, perhaps by using arrays?

```
Data have;
x1 = 1;
x2 = 2;
x3 = 3;
x4 = 4;
Run;

Data want;
Set have;
y1 = x1*2;
y2 = x2*2;
y3 = x3*2;
y4 = x4*2;
Run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two arrays like this:

```
data want;
   set have;
   array varx x:;
   array vary y1-y4;
   do over varx;
      vary=varx*2;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Would be better to make the VARX array in the same way as the VARY.  That way if HAVE has less than 4 X variables the data step does not crash for indexing beyond the array.